# How to disable future date in angular-moment-picker.js?

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How to disable future date in angular-moment-picker.js?
My code is

```
<div class="input-group"
 moment-picker="ctrl.datepicker"
 format="YYYY-MM-DD">
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="octicon octicon-calendar"></i>
</span>
<input class="form-control"
       placeholder="Select a date"
       ng-model="ctrl.datepicker"
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"> </div>
```

Comment: Show us your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set max-date options property to current date.

> max-date   -   Two-way bindable property representing the maximum selectable date (as String in the same format of the value, or as a Moment.js object).

Comment: Please give syntax for max-date upto today .                                                      in controller :                                                                        $scope.dtmax=new Date();  In Html <div class="input-group"  max-date="dtmax"  moment-  picker="ctrl.datepicker"
 format="YYYY-MM-DD">
   But not working